# printing error variable not defined

Tags: python

The following code is causing an cp_exact is not defined error. I can't figure out why.

Essentially the error is in the end line that goes generically as 
print("%10.6f, %10.6f, %10.6f" % (a, b, c)). Why doesn't think work? a, b, c, are defined, but it throws an "a is not defined" error.

```
def print_result():
    #Exact call and put based on Black Scholes
    exact_call = V_c(0.75, 0.025, 1, 0, 100, 100, 0.03)
    exact_put = V_p(0.75, 0.025, 1, 0, 100, 100, 0.03)
    #Put these into an array
    cp_exact = [exact_call, exact_put]
    #Euler call and put prices
    cp_euler = CP_Euler(100, 0.08, 0.03, 0.75, 1, 100, 100, 1000)
    #Compute error in call and put prices
    cp_error = Error_Euler(100, 0.08, 0.03, 0.75, 1, 100, 100, 1000, 0.025)
    print("Black-Scholes Euler Discretization Comparison\n\
    with the following parameters: Stock = $100, Strike = $100\n\
    mu = 0.08, r = 0.03, delta = 0.025, sigma = 0.75, T = 1\n\
    dt = 0.01, N = 1000")
    print("Exact Call        Euler Call             Error")
    print("%10.6f %10.6f %10.6f" % (cp_exact[0], cp_euler[0], cp_error[0]))
```

Comment: On your first print statement, is it multiple lines in the source code? If that is the case, use 3 quotations instead of one: `print("""hello there! """)`

Comment: The code in my program actually doesn't have the last couple lines indented! That's the root of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not thinking straight. I simply wasn't indenting. So, I was printing variables that didn't exist. Eventually I'll get used to this python style of the code belonging to a function is simply indented, not braced.

Comment: Make sure you select your own answer as the answer to the question if you've solved your problem!